# Increasing the width of navigation items with transition on hover

Tags: html, css

Whenever you hover over the navigation bar, it should extend the width of the hovered link. Currently nothing happens.

- `.p1` is the navigation menu words.
- the `.nav`s are the boxes surrounding just the single word menu, and `.container` is the nav container.

Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background: url(wallpaper.png);
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  height: 125px;
}
body {
  background: url(391336.jpg);
}
#container {
  background: black;
  background: url(wallpaper.png);
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav1 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #B201F5;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav2 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FF8600;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav3 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FD0017;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav4 {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #09EB00;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.p1 {
  font-family: "ChunkFive Roman";
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.nav1:hover {
  width=900px;
}
.nav2:hover {
  width=900px;
}
.nav3:hover {
  width=900px;
}
.nav4:hover {
  width=900px;
}
#nav {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Other Side Of Me</h1>
<div id="container">
  <div class="nav1">
    <p class="p1">About me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav2">
    <p class="p1">ShowCase</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav3">
    <p class="p1">Hobby</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav4">
    <p class="p1">Contact</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jeeeeeeeeeeeeezus! So many `<br />`s that I'm afraid to even edit your question.

Comment: Just copy the top part, paste it into a new notepad then see from there

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Copy code to notepad? That defeats the purpose of code blocks and proper formatting. Please format your question accordingly.

Comment: Done formatting, pls its formatted now, dont downvote D:

Comment: To start with... typo `width = 900px;` should be `width: 900px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a typo on your hover widths — `width = 900px` should be `width: 900px`.

That said, even when you get it working, the other links will be pushed onto a new line if the browsers viewport isn't wide enough.

### One solution is to use `display: table` / `display: table-cell`

**Compatibility:** [IE 8+ and all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)

**Firstly, let's improve our markup:**

- [A `<nav>` seems appropriate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav) to wrap it all together.
- The `<p>` is for a paragraph of text, which these certainly are not. Let's just use the `<a>`. Together we get this:

  ```
      <nav id="primary">
          <a>Nav Link Text</a>
      </nav>
  ```

Now let's simplify your CSS. The properties that all the links share can be given with `#primary a`; this way you don't have to repeat the same properties for every class.

**To achieve our layout using `display: table`:**

- remove the floats
- give the nav element `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed`
- give the a elements `display: table-cell` and `width: 25%` (100% width of table / 4 "table cells"). This is required for the width to have a smooth transition.
- when the nav is hovered, remove all the non-hovered links widths [using the `:not` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not); this will give the entire width of the nav to the hovered link:

  ```
  #primary:hover a:not(:hover) {
    width: 0%;
  }
  ```

  Every link that is not hovered is given a 0% width. The `overflow: hidden` on `<a>` hides the text.
- [The not selector is pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), but let's provide a fallback for browsers that do not support it. The hovered cell is given a larger width:

  ```
  #primary a:hover { 
      width: 50%;
  }
  ```

### Complete Example

In this example, the nav has a `max-width: 1000px` to prevent it getting too wide.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#primary {
  background: black;
  background: url(wallpaper.png);
  height: 100px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#primary a {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 25%;
  background: #B201F5;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  transition: width .2s ease-in-out, line-height .5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "ChunkFive Roman";
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#primary .nav2 {
  background: #FF8600;
}
#primary .nav3 {
  background: #FD0017;
}
#primary .nav4 {
  background: #09EB00;
}
#primary a:hover {
  width: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#primary:hover a:not(:hover) {
  width: 0%;
}
```

```html
<h1>The Other Side Of Me</h1>
<nav id="primary">
  <a class="nav1">About me</a>
  <a class="nav2">ShowCase</a>
  <a class="nav3">Hobby</a>
  <a class="nav4">Contact</a>
</nav>
```